# Mysql error while trying to make a login php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I'm new at this site, and at programming too. The thing is that I am trying to do a login page and it doesnt work. I dont get any error message it just doesnt login even if I put the right login.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

$sqli = " SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = $user AND password = $pass ";

if(!$result = $db->query($sqli)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($check_user>0){

    echo "Te has conectado";
} else {

    echo "Vuelve a intentarlo";
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Show the HTML you are using for the `<form>` and its input fields. _Edit your question, dont add this as a comment_ As you are not getting the user and password from either the $_POST or $_GET arrays. There area few other obvious issues but lets start with that one

Comment: Encapsulate $username and $password by single quotes within the sql string.

Comment: You are also mixing Proceedural and OO `mysqli_` thats not a good idea

Comment: Is your PHP setup with error reporting? Try adding this to the top of your script so you can see an error message at least. ```<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>```